# Laravel Eloquent whereHas with minimum children count

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Ok so i have this query:

```
 $chat_existing = Chat::whereHas('members', function ( $query) use ($members) {
        $query->whereIn('author_id', $members);
    })->get();
```

This returns all chats contain these members.  `DB::enableQueryLog()` reveals the query run to be as follows:

```
select * from `chats` where exists (select * from `chat_users` where `chats`.`id`
 = `chat_users`.`chat_id` and `author_id` in ("1-bob-1234","1-jeff-1234"))
```

What I have not been able to figure out his how to structure my eloquent query to show me only the chats where the count is equal to the total number of members.  This is the query that gives me the result:

```
select * from `chats` where (select count(*) from `chat_users` where `chats`.`id`
 = `chat_users`.`chat_id` and `author_id` in ("1-bob-1234","1-jeff-1234")) = 2
```

How can i get laravel to do this?

Comment: the 3rd and 4th arguments to `whereHas` are an operator and a count

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, that totally worked! I can't give you credit i don't think? if you don't post it as an answeR?